# Arduino Nano with Arduin Nano Ethernet shield ENC28J60

Tags: arduino-nano, ethernet-shield

I have connected the Arduino Nano with the Arduino Nano ENC28J60, and then I connect the Ethernet cable with the laptop and also the Arduino nano with my laptop to load the code and it works just fine.

I was wondering if I want to disconnect the Arduino Nano with the laptop and run the same code then, how should I put the external power supply on ENC28J60 and what should be, and in general, what should be the right wiring?

Comment: use a phone charger

Comment: phone charger is not functional, I want to use for example, power supply, is it possible;

Comment: phone charger is power supply. why is it "not functional"? you can use the Vin pin of Nano as it is documented on the shop page. https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano